# Get search results by relationship

Tags: relations, search

I have a section of "video" entries which are related to another section via an "area" field in the "video" section. When you do a search  on the front end by area then the related video displays as expected. What I also have in the area section is a text field full of postcodes, what I would like to happen is when you then do a search by postcode then the video displays that is related to that area, is that possible?

Here is my code that works for searches by area:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('search') %}
{% set searchEntries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}

{% for entry in searchEntries.video(':notempty:') %}
  {% set video = entry.video %}
  {{ video.embed({ width: 340, height: 191, showinfo: false }) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do another call to `craft.entries` when you loop through the "area" entries and include the `section` and `relatedTo` params:

```
{% for entry in searchEntries %}
    {% set videos = craft.entries.section('videoSectionHandle').relatedTo(entry) %}
    {% for video in videos %}
         {# Output video here #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you're trying to maintain a one-to-one relationship it might make sense to limit the relation query to one result, and to include the `first` param to return the first (and only) result and not an array – then you can omit the nested `for` loop:

```
{% for entry in searchEntries %}
    {% set video = craft.entries.section('videoSectionHandle').relatedTo(entry).limit(1).first() %}
    {{ video ? #--Output video here--# }}
{% endfor %}
```

[You can read more about the relatedTo param here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param), it's pretty powerful.